# Discord.js - SyntaxError: Unexpected token )

Tags: javascript, nodejs

Estoy programando un bot para Discord y me he encontrado con un problema al escribir un archivo en JSON.

```
fs.writeFile('./storage/botconfig.json', JSON.stringify(botConfig), (err) => {
        if (err) console.error(err);
      });
```

---

Esto es el error que me devuelve la consola.

```
/home/pi/bots/discordbot/commands/configSet.js:29
});
 ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token )
    at new Script (vm.js:80:7)
    at createScript (vm.js:274:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:326:10)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:664:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:712:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:600:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:539:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:531:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)
```

[image: Contenido del JSON (botconfig.json)]

Comment: Necesitaríamos ver el contenido de ese Json para decirte algo más, parece ser que hay un carácter ilegal, pero sin el contenido no podemos hacer nada. Un saludo

Comment: Ya he publicado el contenido del archivo en cuestión.

Comment: ¿Puedes indicar cuál es la linea 29 de tu archivo ***configSet.js***? El error lo marca en esa línea, y no parece relacionado con tu archivo *json*. Si fuese el caso el error sería *parse error*.

Comment: En el configSet.js no hay línea 29, el código que pongo es lo único que lleva "});"

Comment: Por alguna razón la [documentación](https://discordjs.guide/preparations/setting-up-a-linter.html#setting-up-eslint-rules) de ***Discord.js*** recomienda usar un Linter, para evitar este tipo de errores de sintaxis. ¿Qué sucede si cambias tu ***single-line if*** por un `if` tradicional con llaves y multilinea? Como te dije, el error no parece de *parsear* el JSON. Puedes leer la documentación de [ESLint](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/brace-style) para mayor información. ¿Podrías verificar eso? Saludos

Comment: @MauricioContreras el problema es que no es ni un _if_ ni un **_single-line if_**, al parecer es una función de el **fs** al escribir un archivo.

Comment: Pues por más que lo pruebo no puedo reproducir tu error. No hay nada que indique que algo falle a primera vista. Un simple archivo que realiza la misma tarea que tienes en tu código, se ejecuta correctamente en mi equipo, uso Node v11.11.0, pero eso no creo que sea el problema tampoco. Lo siento, pero no se que más aportar.

Answer (score 0):

El error es básico simplemente te falta `)`, te dejo el código correcto.

```
    fs.writeFile('./storage/botconfig.json', JSON.stringify(botConfig), (err) => {
            if (err) console.error(err));
});
```

Comment: Ese código esta mal, agregaste un paréntesis demás. El error no ocurre por sintáxis. Saludos